# How do I list file in time order using the SFTP module of NET::SSH2 in Perl?

Tags: perl, list, ssh, sftp

I am using SFTP through the NET::SSH2 package in Perl.
Listing files in a folder works good using the opendir function.

I would like to have the files in time order with the latest modified file last.
Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hashes returned by `Net::SSH2::Dir::read` method have and entry called `mtime` which indicates the time the entry was modified. Use it to sort the entries:

```
my @e;
my $dir = $sftp->opendir($dir);

while (my $e = $dir->read) {
  push @e, $e;
}

@e = sort { $a->{mtime} <=> $b->{mtime} } @e;
print "$_->{name}\n" for @e;
```

Comment: Awesome! I only had to add the sort line to my code and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

cant you just execute using `exec('ls -t')` through plain `SSH`? (without `SFTP`).

something like:

```
my $chan = $ssh2->channel();
$chan->exec('ls -t'); # executed in the dir you would like to get the files sorted from
```

Comment: Yes, maybe that could work. Is there a possibility that a server only has SFTP and not SSH? Regular servers with Linux should have both but what if it is a branded SFTP server? Using this solution; how do I first change directory?